# Redirect Http to HTTPS only for certain endpoints

Tags: tomcat, redirect, portforwarding

I have successfully configured my Tomcat to redirect from port 80 to 443. However, is Tomcat smart enough to only redirect certain endpoints to 443 while allowing others to access port 80? 
For example, I only want endpoints that are reached from http://myWebsite/myBankAccount/* to be redirected to https. But if you were to just access http://myWebsite.com, Tomcat will allow port 80 access. 
If Tomcat is not smart enough to implement this, what application can do this?

Comment: I suggest adding your current tomcat configuration to your question. It'll help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `url-pattern` element. Here's an example:

```
<!-- Require HTTPS for everything that matches the url pattern: /myBankAccount/* -->
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>HTTPSOnly</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/myBankAccount/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using Spring-Security, then you can also adjust it's configuration to require (or allow) a different protocol based on the URL pattern.

For example, see [Spring HTTP/HTTPS Channel Security](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-channel-security-https).